# display vf page in standard object when we select picklist value

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component

hi friends,
                     i want to display vf pages in standard object (account) when i select pick-list value it display VF page in page layout

Comment: you can't perform that at the same time you are making the change in picklist but once you click save page will refresh and you can put same logic in rerender attribute inside your visualforce page.

Comment: ok,thanx himanshu,

Comment: is there any chance to do this ...

Comment: In account object we have a standard picklist value,suppose i select picklist value then we have to display the vf page in existing record,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot show/hide things conditionally in a Standard Page Layout. You can try VF for that type of logic.

Comment: Thanx for response @sebastin, i agree with u its not possible to show hide.

Comment: I done the issue

Comment: Can you marked the question as answered, then, so more users can benefit? :)